# alternatives to PHASTER phage annotation server

Tags: sequence-annotation

I would like to use PHASTER (http://phaster.ca) from the University of Alberta, but it's currently down for maintenance, as is its predecessor, PHAST.

What alternatives to PHASTER are there for searching and annotating phage sequences within assembled genomes?

EDIT:

I have seen that PROKKA has some entries mentioning the possibility of using PHASER (currently discarded as an option) but also people using their own HMMs to annotate phage sequences using PROKKA, e.g.:
https://github.com/tseemann/prokka/issues/375

Any ideas?

Comment: Phigaro https://github.com/bobeobibo/phigaro, Virsorter

Comment: Thanks @Chris_Rands , I had a look at phigaro, and I like the fact that the pVOG families give an annotation for things like tail fiber proteins and the rest. Useful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `phastaf`, a recently developed software tool developed by Torsten Seemann (the same developer as prokka), which comes with a packaged phaster.ca db.  Get it [here](https://github.com/tseemann/phastaf)

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.